# How we can obfuscate twitter api key and secret in android apps

Tags: android, twitter

How we can obfuscate twitter api key and secret in android apps? If not possible how we can keep safe these keys from hackers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [Fabric for Android](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html)

It's should be the same for Twitter api. The idea is to remove your keys from the manifest and put it in the *gradle.properties* file. Same for example if you want to build a signed apk using gradle. You can put you passwords in the *gradles.properties*.

Another possible solution is to make a **library in C++ or NDK** and put there your key. It can't be decompiled easily like a jar.